# Why can't STATIC_URL begin with 'http://' or '/' for a DJango dev server?

Tags: django

Recently I've been wanting to add a load of functionality to my site. To make that process faster I wanted to serve the static files off my dev machine. Specifically, I wanted to use the built-in dev server that ships with DJango v1.3.1; modifying the production server is a bad idea and having to upload the static files each time they're altered was wasting a lot of time and energy.

Getting the dev serve to play ball however has been a nightmare! I've just wasted about 4 hours trying to get to serve up static data and it turns out all I had wrong was that the dev server doesn't appear to like a '/' at the beginning of `STATIC_URL`? I'd like to know why and/or what I'm doing wrong...

I've been trying to use [the settings suggested in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) but either I've mis-read something or there's more to this.

My project looks like this:

```
<project root>
    /app1
        ..various files..
    /app2
        ..various files..
    /static
        /style
            Style.css
    /templates
manage.py
settings.py
settings_dev.py
settings_production.py
urls.py
```

My `settings.py` detects which server we're running on and calls the appropriate `settings_dev.py` or `settings_production.py` which works well and all my settings work fine on the productions server.

My `settings_dev.py` has the following:

```
DEBUG = True

ADMINS = (
    ('Jon', 'jon@mydomain'),
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = '/media'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/jon/PycharmProjects/myproject/static'
STATIC_URL = 'http://192.168.1.4/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://192.168.1.4/static/admin/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('C:/Users/jon/PycharmProjects/myproject/templates',)

IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER=False
```

..and `urls.py` includes the following:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'app1.views.index'),
    (r'^/$', 'app1.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER is False:
    print 'Adding DJango static serving from %s'%settings.STATIC_ROOT
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

This works in so much as my templates pick up the static url and give me (for example) `http://192.168.1.4/static/style/Style.css` *but* if I change `STATIC_URL` to `/static`

...and then visit `http://192.168.1.4/static/style/Style.css` I get a 404 error:

```
'\style\Style.css' could not be found
```

So what's going on?

Comment: Is your dev server really running on `http://192.168.1.4` and not, say, `http://192.168.1.4:8000`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some special helpers to route the urls to static files

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.IS_PRODUCTION_SERVER is False:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Also, I never checked the sources to see if it matters, but in all the examples in the original settings.py STATIC_ROOT,STATIC_URL,MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT end with /, you could give it a try.

If you're in dispair, after too many start of Django projects where I forget to set something I made a generic all purpose django base project, you can find it at https://github.com/riquito/Semiautomatic-django-setup